# How to use watchEffect for a store value?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to trigger a fetch request from a sibling component. For this, I have a `pages/index.vue` component with a button to switch a store variable, like below:

`pages/index.vue`:

```
<script setup>
import { mystore } from "../stores/mystore.js";
</script>

<template>
  <v-btn @click="mystore.setMyVariable(true)">Refresh</v-btn>
</template>
```

`stores/mystore.js`:

```
import { ref } from "vue";

export const mystore = ref({
  myVariable: false,
  setMyVariable(value) {
    this.myVariable = value;
  },
});
```

Then, I have a `components/foo.vue` component to check the change and trigger the fetch:
`components/foo.vue`:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, watchEffect } from "vue";
import { mystore } from "../../../stores/mystore.js";

const { data: thedata, refresh } = await useFetch(
  "http://api.test/foo",
  {
    transform(data) {
      return JSON.parse(data);
    },
    pick: ["data"],
  }
);

const headers = reactive([
  { title: "ID", key: "id" },
  { title: "Name", key: "name" }
]);

watchEffect(() => {
  console.log("test");
  console.log(mystore.myVariable); // → "undefied" in the console
});
</script>

<template>

  Should refresh ? {{ mystore.myVariable }}

  <v-data-table
    v-if="thedata"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="thedata.data"
  ></v-data-table>

</template>
```

In the template, I can see that `myVariable` has changed, but `watchEffect()` is just showing `undefined` once.

What's wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using [ref](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref) the inner value is accessed with `.value` so the watchEffect needs to be changed to:

```js
watchEffect(() => {
  console.log('test');
  console.log(mystore.value.myVariable);
});
```

You don't have to use `.value` in `<template>` because it's automatically unwrapped when used there

Comment: Side question: how to call the refresh from watchEffect?

Comment: refresh is a normal function returned by `useFetch` so you can just do `refresh();`